# Is Flux' Dispatcher over-engineering since Javascript is single-threaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I was looking at how Flux's [Dispatcher.js](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js) is implemented, which raised some questions in light of my understanding that javascript is single threaded:

Will `isDispatching()` ever return anything other than `false`? The `_isDispatching` flag is set in the beginning of `dispatch()` and then set back to `false` right before the end of the method. If there is only one thread executing the `Dispatcher`, what else can call `isDispatching()`?

Similarly, aren't `_isPending` and `_isHandled` booleans on each callback superfluous?

Answer (score 0):

They're there as checks to prevent a callback from immediately attempting to dispatch again (causing infinite loops.)

Try to picture what would happen if one of the listeners called dispatch while the previous dispatch was still looping through `this._callbacks`